# Getting warning message while doing npm install. Let me know the right approach to remove the warning message

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, linux, npm-install

I tried with **npm install** but still getting these warning message. let me know the steps to remove these warning messages.

````
 deprecated. Please use eslint-webpack-plugin npm WARN deprecated
 chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to
 chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies. npm WARN deprecated
 popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core,
 this package is dedicated to the legacy v1 npm WARN deprecated
 request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see
 https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142 npm WARN deprecated
 request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native has been
 deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see
 https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142 npm WARN deprecated
 @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi' npm WARN deprecated
 fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be
 using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2. npm WARN deprecated
 har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported npm WARN
 deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see
 https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated npm WARN deprecated
 @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address' npm WARN
 deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is
 no longer supported or maintained npm WARN deprecated
 @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer
 supported or maintained npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This
 version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
 npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1:
 https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated npm WARN deprecated
 left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart() npm WARN deprecated
 core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not
 recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade
 your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.```
````

Comment: which node version are you using?